# Write Android Espresso test

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I need to write a UI test to validate that clicking the floating action button results in displaying the SecondActivity.

```
public class MainActivityTest {

  @Rule
  public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
        MainActivity.class);

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {

  }

  @Test
  public void onClick() throws Exception {
      onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click());
  }
}
```

Is it enough?

And how can I validate that the Activity properly displays the text contents of an incoming object: name, age, phone number?

I have just started using espresso(

Comment: What do you mean by "incoming object" in your 2nd question?

Comment: @PhilippeA I have object with fields: name, age and phone number. These fields fill the view on the screen. How can I check the correct completion of views?

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: @PhilippeA If the text is taken from the database, how can I access the records?

Comment: You need to mock the database in your test and have it return the text value that you want, so you can verify that it is displayed.

Comment: @PhilippeA Thank you, but I don't know how to mock(

Comment: You should ask another question for that, it's not related to Espresso or even Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it enough?

No, it is not enough. This code
`onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click());` only performs a click on the button, but there is nothing that verifies that the application behaved correctly after that.

To verify that an intent to open the SecondActivity was created, you need to use [Espresso Intents](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/#intent-validation).

> how can I validate that the Activity properly displays the text contents of an incoming object

You can use something like:

`onView(withId(R.id.textView)).check(matches(withText("Expected text")));`

Take a look at the [Espresso Cheatsheet](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/cheatsheet/index.html) for more.

Comment: So I should add 
`intended(toPackage(com.android.SecondActivity));`
or I should add:
user.clickOnView(system.getView(R.id.Button));
intended(toPackage(com.android.SecondActivity));

Comment: You should add `intended(...)`